# document.body in content.js returns html from popup.html not the webpage

Tags: javascript, regex, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a profanity filter for chrome and when I use `document.body` to get the html from the page to apply the filter or when I use something like

```
var webUrl = chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true},)
```

I just get an undefined variable.

I was wondering for any pointers where I'm going wrong, or any other method to be able to search through the text on a web page and apply a RegExp to filter for me.

Cheers for any help!

Comment: You didn't show how you load content.js. Also, Chrome API is asynchronous so your `webUrl` will be `undefined`. Use callbacks or a [Promise polyfill by Mozilla](https://github.com/mozilla/webextension-polyfill). See the documentation and google up examples, there are tons of those.